# How to config apache reply for some request and not sent that for tornado

Tags: python, apache, tornado

I have a web site that wrote by python and tornado.
Apache is my web server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName food.domain.com
    ProxyPass /  http://127.0.0.1:8004/ retry=0 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On

    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8004/
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    DocumentRoot /var/food

    <Directory /var/food/ >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php.error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In my site the `static` files begins with `/static` for example:

```
http://food.domain.com/static/favicon.ico
http://food.domain.com/static/upload/main/20x20_73213076755756.png
```

Now apache remise all urls to `tornado` server.

I want the URLS begin with `static` not send to tornado and that file replayed by apache or otherwise.

what is best solution?

Comment: Have you tried `Alias /path/to/static/files`?

Comment: Add this line before proxy settings. Alias /static /path/to/static/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply exclude that path from [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) with exclamation mark:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName food.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/food
    ProxyPass /static !

    ProxyPass /  http://127.0.0.1:8004/ retry=0 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On

    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8004/
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Directory /var/food/ >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php.error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If your statics are at /var/food/static then there is nothing else to do.